# setTimeout не работает в делегированном событии

Tags: javascript

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    // Добавление класса перетаскивания к элементу после задержки
    setTimeout(() => item.classList.add('dragging'), 0);
});
// Удаление класса перетаскивания из элемента в событии dragend
 item.addEventListener('dragend', () => item.classList.remove('dragging'));
});
```

```html
    <ul class="sortable-list">
        <li class="item" data-item="217" draggable="true">Text-1</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="216" draggable="true">Text-2</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="215" draggable="true">Text-3</li>
    </ul>
```

Данные получаю через json, и уже в JS скрипте вывожу их. Это у меня сортировка списка задач, при перетаскивания списка, должен вешаться класс ".dragging", а когда переместили, то должен удаляться. Читал я про делегирования события, навешал обработчик на предка, но класс почти что не ставиться, он за долю секунда появился и исчезает.....
Не могу понять как это побороть, сам код работает, потому что, когда выводил данные через PHP, то я отлавливал, но там не было делегированности!

```
// работаю через предка
const sortableList = document.querySelector('.sortable-list');

sortableList.addEventListener('click', function () {

const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        setTimeout(() => item.classList.add('dragging'), 0);
    });

    //item.addEventListener('dragend', () => item.classList.remove('dragging'));
});
});

// также пробывал без предка
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    // Добавление класса перетаскивания к элементу после задержки
    setTimeout(() => item.classList.add('dragging'), 0);
});
// Удаление класса перетаскивания из элемента в событии dragend
 item.addEventListener('dragend', () => item.classList.remove('dragging'));
});


   // это в обычном простое
    <ul class="sortable-list">
        <li class="item" data-item="217">Text-1</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="216">Text-2</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="215">Text-3</li>
    </ul>

   // это когда я перемещаю, то класс dragging появляется
    <ul class="sortable-list">
        <li class="item" data-item="217">Text-1</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="216">Text-2</li>
        <li class="item dragging" data-item="215">Text-3</li>
    </ul>

   // это уже когда я переместил, то класс dragging удаляется задача перемещена
    <ul class="sortable-list">
        <li class="item" data-item="217">Text-1</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="215">Text-3</li>
        <li class="item" data-item="216">Text-2</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `.dragging` может глючить внутри `setTimeout`, браузер может успеть выполнить удаление класса до того, как он вообще появится на элементе. Можно использовать [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) для более точного управления анимацией и изменениями DOM.

Comment: @DiMithras requestAnimationFrame как я прочитал и понял, он используется для animation, то что я перемещаю списке между собой, это же не является анимацией???

Comment: Под вашу задачу тоже подходит. Скажем так, могу наглядно в snippet показать и с `setTimeout` и с `requestAnimationFrame`, думаю оба отработают одинаково, но в вашем случае может перехватит баг, в котором класс сбрасывается. Вам бы в snippet запихнуть для наглядности.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame(() => item.classList.add('dragging')); правильно сделал???

Comment: Даㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: По пробовал в коде, нуль реакции

Comment: Чтож, жаль. Тогда могу посоветовать ставить точку остановы на `dragend` и `dragstart` и смотреть что их тригеррит, в рамках сниппета всё нормально работает.

Comment: Да работает, на codepen отдельно проверил..... на счет requestAnimationFrame я не знал, так что буду иметь виду... я лучше утром посмотрю)

Comment: Народ какие есть еще варианты

Comment: Вы же написали, что работает. Внимание к вопросу можно привлечь через конкурс, не ваш вариант, к сожалению, либо в чате (дурной совет, но всё же).

Comment: У меня в коде не работает, потому что надо.... я так думаю делать через делегирование событие, а работал он в статике, в динамике нет.

Answer (score 0):

Раскрою мысль из комментов в ответе.
Тут пример с `requestAnimationFrame`. С ним чуть больше уверенности, что всё отработает правильно и изменение класса будет происходить в нужный момент. Так код выполняется при следующем рендеринге браузера, что более надёжно и предсказуемо.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        item.classList.add('dragging');
        item.querySelector('.color-indicator').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
    });

    item.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        item.classList.remove('dragging');
        item.querySelector('.color-indicator').style.backgroundColor = '';
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.sortable-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: grab;
  user-select: none;
}

.dragging {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.color-indicator {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sortable-list">
  <li class="item" data-item="217" draggable="true">Text-1 <span class="color-indicator"></span></li>
  <li class="item" data-item="216" draggable="true">Text-2 <span class="color-indicator"></span></li>
  <li class="item" data-item="215" draggable="true">Text-3 <span class="color-indicator"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Для наглядности, когда появляется класс, на элементе списка возникает красный кружок, когда класс удаляется, кружок исчезает. (чтобы не делать это вычурно через alert'ы)

В этом же snippet можно и `setTimeout` использовать как у вас:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.add('dragging');
        item.querySelector('.color-indicator').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }, 0);
    });

    item.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.remove('dragging');
        item.querySelector('.color-indicator').style.backgroundColor = '';
      }, 0);
    });
  });
});
```

И работает он в рамках snippet'а без проблем, по крайней мере у меня. Но есть нюанс. Если поиграться со значениями `setTimeout` и поставить не `}, 0);`, а, допустим, 1000, начинаются баги

Моё предположение, что у вас браузер нулевые значения отрабатывает с глюками, и `requestAnimationFrame`, возможно, решит вашу проблему, т.к. более надёжен.